# Manually using pg_connect in a model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, postgresql

Why doesn't this code work in a model in codeigniter. It works perfectly in "normal" php (with the same variables for the connection).

```
$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
                or die ("Could not connect to server\n");
```

The following error pops up after some amount of time:

```
Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to
server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "198.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting 
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The answer to this, is as I know, yes

Comment: Btw, I have tried connecting to multiple databases following various tutorials, it does not work, but I get other errors. I am connecting to this external database to fetch some data from a sister site.

Comment: When you say it works in "normal" PHP, is this ran on the same server as Codeigniter with the errors?

Comment: No, another server. However, on the CI server, I have the option to use a postgres database, so would it not be fair to assume the server can handle this? Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Try the "normal" php script on the CI server (but outside of the CI installation). If it doesn't work, then your database server isn't allowing access from the CI server.

Comment: I'm thinking that the remote PostgreSQL server you are connecting to has restricted access (possibly only `localhost`, or specific IPs).  This is default activity for security reasons.  Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150738/cannot-connect-to-postgres-from-remote-host).

Comment: @Sam - This is already fixed :)

Comment: @Samutz - No, I can't run the code outside Codeigniter on the same server... But I did set up the database server to allow any IP to connect to it...

Comment: @Øyvind What about a firewall on either server possibly blocking the connection?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem on the database server, as I did everything by the book to open for all IPs. How can I find out if there is something blocking it on the CI server? It is a server run by a hosting company, running Cpanel, giving me some limitations.

Comment: _Connection timed out_ is typical of a firewall dropping the network packets. Check with your hosting provider what kind of outbound traffic is allowed.