# "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused" Error when connecting to remote database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, centos7

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database installed in a remote server using the following command:

psql -h `host_ip` -U `db_username` -d `db_name`

This is the error that occurs:

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "<host_ip>" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

1. Postgres installed version is 9.4.
2. Host operating system: Ubuntu 15.04
3. Client operating system: Centos 7

I already tried the following but the issue remains unresolved:

1. Edited `pg_hba.conf` file to include

> host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0  md5

2. Edited 'postgresql.conf' and changed the listen parameter to

> listen_addresses='*'

3. Restarted Postgres service.
4. Disabled firewall and iptables on host and client.
5. I checked by running the psql command locally and it worked.
6. I tried the second solution given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150738/cannot-connect-to-postgres-from-remote-host). Running `nmap` gave me the following output:

`Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-07 18:08 IST Nmap scan report for 10.17.250.250 Host is up (0.0000040s latency). Not shown: 997 closed ports PORT   STATE SERVICE 22/tcp open  ssh 25/tcp open  smtp 80/tcp open  http`

Am I missing something? Hope someone can help.

Comment: firewall is still blocking port 5432. check your configs for iptables.

Comment: @Dmitry I disabled iptables by running `sudo ufw disable`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try a 'netstat -na|grep 5432' and see if postgresql binds to all interfaces?

Comment: Only this statement saved me spending hell lot of time host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
cd /etc/postgresql/9.x/main/
```

open file named `postgresql.conf`

```
sudo vi postgresql.conf
```

**{Note:-(You can use sudo "nano") If facing issues with editing through vi(Vim)]**

add this line to that file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

then open file named `pg_hba.conf`

```
sudo vi pg_hba.conf
```

and add this line to that file

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password

## restart your server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: Hi, is not working at UBUNTU 16 LTS with pg9.5... Do you have a complete `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` scripts adapted to this env and permissions?  I need to use `PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres`.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I am facing the issue. It is not working at UBUNTU 16 LTS with pg9.5. Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry @Arpit, was 2017... The best solution today (near 2020) is to upgrade UBUNTU to 18 LTS and PostgreSQL  to v11+.

Comment: After upgrading from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 16 I received this error. Simply restarting postgresql worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For the poor soul who also happens upon this, try also replacing your pg_hba.conf with a `default` version. fml.

Comment: Just doing the first step worked for me - Ubuntu, Django

Answer (score 35):

Check the port defined in `postgresql.conf`. My installation of postgres 9.4 uses port `5433` instead of `5432`

Comment: Just wanted to add that this also happened to my `postgresql.conf` in Postgres 11... never minded to check `postgresql.conf` but fixing it to 5432 was all it took.

Comment: It happened with me too, Postgres 12.

Comment: Bizarre, I picked 5432 in the installer menu and there it is, 5433. So it affects new versions rather than old

Answer (score 13):

I have struggled with this when trying to remotely connect to a new PostgreSQL installation on my Raspberry Pi. Here's the full breakdown of what I did to resolve this issue:

First, open the PostgreSQL configuration file and make sure that the service is going to listen outside of localhost.

```
sudo [editor] /etc/postgresql/[version]/main/postgresql.conf
```

I used `nano`, but you can use the editor of your choice, and while I have version `9.1` installed, that directory will be for whichever version you have installed.

Search down to the section titled 'Connections and Authentication'. The first setting should be `'listen_addresses'`, and might look like this:

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

The comments to the right give good instructions on how to change this field, and using the suggested `'*'` for all will work well.

Please note that this field is commented out with #. Per the comments, it will default to 'localhost', so just changing the value to `'*'` isn't enough, you also need to uncomment the setting by removing the leading `#`.

It should now look like this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

You can also check the next setting, 'port', to make sure that you're connecting correctly. 5432 is the default, and is the port that psql will try to connect to if you don't specify one.

Save and close the file, then open the Client Authentication config file, which is in the same directory:

```
sudo [editor] /etc/postgresql/[version]/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I recommend reading the file if you want to restrict access, but for basic open connections you'll jump to the bottom of the file and add a line like this:

```
host all all all md5
```

You can press tab instead of space to line the fields up with the existing columns if you like.

Personally, I instead added a row that looked like this:

```
host [database_name] pi 192.168.1.0/24 md5
```

This restricts the connection to just the one user and just the one database on the local area network subnet.

Once you've saved changes to the file you will need to restart the service to implement the changes.

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now you can check to make sure that the service is openly listening on the correct port by using the following command:

```
sudo netstat -ltpn
```

If you don't run it as elevated (using `sudo`) it doesn't tell you the names of the processes listening on those ports.

One of the processes should be Postgres, and the Local Address should be open (0.0.0.0) and not restricted to local traffic only (127.0.0.1). If it isn't open, then you'll need to double check your config files and restart the service. You can again confirm that the service is listening on the correct port (default is `5432`, but your configuration could be different).

Finally you'll be able to successfully connect from a remote computer using the command:

```
psql -h [server ip address] -p [port number, optional if 5432] -U [postgres user name] [database name]
```

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the settings are applied correctly in the config file.

```
vim /etc/postgresql/x.x/main/postgresql.conf
```

Try the following to see the logs and find your problem.

```
tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-x.x-main.log
```

Comment: Thanks @amirio , this is right way to find exact problem.
In my case, there was problem related to file permissions
2019-05-20 19:53:45.406 IST [4843] FATAL:  data directory `"/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" has group or world access
2019-05-20 19:53:45.406 IST [4843] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).`

Comment: thank you so much for this after checking mu log i saw i had to  give (0700) to my /var/lib/10/main directory it worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Following configuration, you need to set:

To open the port 5432 edit your `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` and change

```
# Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

In /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5
```

Now restart your DBMS

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now you can connect with

```
psql -h hostname(IP) -p port -U username -d database
```

Comment: [at aws ec2] Also I have to edit the inbound port, to accept traffic on 5432.

Answer (score 7):

***Step 1: edit file `potgresql.conf`***

- file location should be : `etc/postgresql/10/main/`
- **Look for:**

  `#Connection Settings -`

  `#listen_addresses = ''          # what IP address(es) to listen on;`
- **remove `#` before listening addresses**
- **add `'*'` :**

  `listen_addresses = '*'`

---

***Step 2: edit file `pg_hba.conf`***

- file location should be : `etc/postgresql/10/main/`
- add below given line at the end

  `host    all    all      0.0.0.0/0     md5`

---

***Step 3: restart postgres server***

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

---

***Step 4: check postgres server status***

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

- **Make sure you are using same port to access the DB**

Answer (score 3):

Mine was quite straightforward if you are on a Mac try:

```
brew install postgres
```

This will tell you if you have it already install and what version or install the latest version for you if not then run

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

This will make sure you have the latest version installed then finally

```
brew services start postgresql
```

This will start the service again. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had removed a locale and generated another locale. Database failed to open because of fatal errors in the postgresql.conf file, on 'lc_messages', 'lc_monetary', 'lc_numberic', and 'lc_time'.

Restoring the locale sorted it out for me.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. This was also the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the machine-name instead of the ip of the host.

I got the same error when i tried with machine's name. Because, It is allowed only when both the client and host are under same network and they have the same Operating system installed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did not change azure default security policy in management portal. The original is port 22 allowed and the rest are all denied. As long as I add 5432 port, everything becomes good.

Answer (score 1):

The following helped me on macos Mojave:

```
$sudo mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres.save
$brew uninstall postgres
$brew install postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

See the port and make a port change in postgresql.conf. My installation of postgres 9.4 uses port 5431 or 5434 instead of 5432.
If it say the port is in use so change the port.
And check if you give password in psql installation so give the password in file and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Another situation,`postgresql.conf`and`pg_hba.conf`file not locate at `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/`.Because postgres can start at any location you set.

For example when you use command `pg_ctl -D /tmp/pgsql/  start` ,the `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` will located at `/tmp/pgsql/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, with my configuration files correct. In my case the issue comes from the Eduroam wifi I used : when I connect via another wifi everything works. It seems that Eduroam blocks port 5432, at least in my university.

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate your database. For instance, if you are using Heroku to host your project and with Django, then try `heroku run python manage.py migrate` command; the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this where I had to ssh into a server and than run a query in psql console so the query was in a script but everytime I got this error psql not found so what I did was just added the psql full path from the bin which we get from cat .bash_profile and its done

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

So I added the whole /usr/local/mysql/bin/psql intead of just psql for remote execution.

Answer (score 0):

and another one here:
both host and remote are on real servers
you need `'*'` exactly.
`'localhost , xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'` will not work. all these answers(i've seen two) should be wiped out.
what you don't need : `host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` and this stuff

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just removed the existing PostgreSQL 14 Server which was on the left-hand side of the pgAdmin4 GUI interface under the servers and then I manually added a new server from the option which is inside Quick Links of pgAdmin4.

I followed the documentation of bitnami.com.

[image: details for adding new server]

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with access to external server via 5432.
I noticed that any network but mine saw the service

```
nmap server -p 5432
```

Fortunatelly, I recalled that I was playing with exposing my internal postgres server to outside world using my mikrotik router.
Somehow it effectively closed external 5432 for internal network.
As soon as I removed all nat rules with 5432 port - it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Windows, I open the task manager, and started the postgres service, then I could connect to the database

[task manager windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3byKm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the host-ip/hostname
if you have connection URL, your host name would be the string between "@" and the db name.

Ex URL:
[postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dpg-clpc4m146foc73a8jr90-a.singapore-postgres.render.com/data_db_1zqi](https://postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dpg-clpc4m146foc73a8jr90-a.singapore-postgres.render.com/data_db_1zqi)

for the above URL host name would be --> dpg-clpc4m146foc73a8jr90-a.singapore-postgres.render.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Check PostgreSQL Service: Ensure that the PostgreSQL service is running. You can check the status of the service using the following command:

   systemctl status postgresql
2. If the service is not running, start it using:

   systemctl start postgresql