# postgres: client could not connect to server

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgis, qgis

For clarification, please note that I have found several similar questions on stackoverflow, but I could not fix my issue.

[psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused” Error when connecting to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439167/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-error-when-connecting-to)

[psql: How to Allow Remote Access to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database)

I am trying to connect to a postgres DB installed in a remote server.
To create a connection from the client I am using QGIS plugin (Add PostGIS Layer):

[image]

The error that occurs is:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432

Additionally I added the host's IP Adress in the Host field, but then another error message occurs:

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "hosts_ip_adress" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

#### My settings are:

1. Postgres installed version is 10.0 with PostGIS extension
2. Host operating System: Windows 7
3. Client operating System: Windows 7

I  edited `pg_hba.conf` to:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

and changes listen parameter in 'postgresql.conf' to:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

both files are located in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data`

4. restartet pgAdmin4

My devices are in the same network. Each one is connected via LAN cable. 
I suppose that a firewall is preventing the connection?

Comment: This is normally a firewall issue.