# pg_hba.conf for Postgresql from Windows Anaconda

Tags: postgresql, anaconda, psycopg2

I've just installed Postgressql (9.5.4 vc14_0) and Psycopg2 (2.7.5 py36h74b6da3_0) and I'm trying to use them within my Anaconda environment on Windows 10.

Whenever I run `psycopg2.connect("host=localhost user=postgres")` in a python interpreter or just `psql` on the command line I get this error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

[I've looked at other Stackoverflow questions regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176520/postgres-client-could-not-connect-to-server), some answers say to look into a pg_hba.conf file although I haven't be able to find any. Where can I find a pg_hba.conf file for my Postgresql in my Anaconda Environment for Windows? If I have to make one, what should go in it? I haven't seen another SO question that uses the same Postgresql-Anaconda-Windows setup that I'm using.

Also I've looked into services.msc but haven't seen a service regarding postgresql.

Comment: The obvious question: is the Postgres Windows service running? The `pb_hba.conf` is always located in the data directory. The graphical installer asks for the location during installation.

Comment: I assume since it's not showing up in `services.msc` that it's not running. My installation is in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\pkgs` but in that directory there's only an `info` and `Library` directory and no `data` subdirectory within those.

Comment: Looks like you did not install Postgres at all then.

Comment: Is it possible to install postgres through conda? I only ran `conda install -c anaconda postgresql`and I'm not sure if I'm missing anything else.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what that conda/anaconda thing is

Comment: 9.5.4 for a new installation? Not a good idea.

Comment: I just took whatever version Conda gave me, is there a specific version on Conda that works best?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error as well. Similar to what you did, I followed the installation page, ran `conda install -c anaconda postgresql` and received the same error in your post.

I have used postgresql through direct installation before, in osx and as far as I can recall, you could just `psql` into the database once the installation is complete.

Maybe this isn't the case for anaconda installations. I overcame this by initializing a new database system in a new, empty folder. In my case, I created a new folder in "\AppData\Local\conda\"

```
-- Initialize the database system
pg_ctl init -D <path_to_your_database_system>

-- Start the database
C:/Users/kerwei/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36/Library/bin/pg_ctl -D <path_to_your_database_system> -l logfile start
```

**NOTE:** After playing around with for awhile, I realized that once you exit the conda environment, the database instance gets terminated too - without properly shutting down. As I don't use it for production stuffs, it doesn't really bother me. However, further steps can be taken to include the database booting and shutting down during `conda activate` or `conda deactivate` to make it less cumbersome.