# Persisting problem to connect to Postgres remotely (connection refused)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, remote-access, psql

I am setting up a server that has more than one Postgres cluster running. By default, I set the main `postgres` cluster (the one whose default port is 5432) to not start automatically with the computer. I set, instead, two other Postgres clusters to start, one at port 5433 and the other at 5434.

All seems to be working perfectly fine, with one critical exception: I can't login to those clusters remotely. That is, when I try:

```
psql -h [my server ip] -p 5433 -U myusername -d mydatabase
```

I get:

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused     Is the server
>   running on host "[my server IP here]" and accepting   TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5433?

Now, I know that past questions have been already asked on this issue. See for instance: ["psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused" Error when connecting to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439167/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-error-when-connecting-to)

However, I did follow all possible steps I found online. Let's see. All my Postgres clusters have their `postgresql.conf` already with `listen_addresses = '*'` (uncommented). Similarly, all my clusters' `pg_hba.conf` have `host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` and `host  all  all all md5`.

I did open ports 5432, 5433 and 5434 with:

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
sudo ufw allow 5433/tcp
sudo ufw allow 5434/tcp
```

And I did restart the postgres services. In fact, I restarted the whole server machine. So now when I run `sudo netstat -ltpn | grep "postgres"` I get, for instance, for cluster at port 5433:

```
tcp      0      0 0.0.0.0:5433     0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      3227/postgres
tcp6     0      0 :::5433          :::*                   LISTEN      3227/postgres
```

Still, remote connection to the Postgres cluster is not possible and throws the above mentioned error. What else can I try?

Comment: Have you tried simple 'ping <your IP>? and 'telnet <your IP> 5333'? In short, are you sure you can establish a TCP/IP connection from your machine to the DB server?

Comment: @GMichael pinging works, but you were right to suggest `telnet`: I get 'Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused'. I have no idea why, since 5432, 5433 and 5434 are already opened.

Comment: It might be that the PG host does not allow incoming connection from your machine. I would completely disable UFW on the DB server (sudo ufw disable) and try again. If it works, try configuring other UFW things, like 'sudo ufw allow from <your application machine IP>'