# Docker Compose Postgres always ended by timeout or connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

Got a small question here. I suppose I've done something wrong at a moment but i can't find where and it's been +2 hours I'm turning around.

So Basically, I've created a docker-compose with Postgis (Postgres). I wanted to connect on it through Tableplus.
However, I can't ...

2 kind of error keep appearing :

1. When I try to connect basically on 127.0.0.1, it's keep telling me connection refused

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

[image: example]

2. When I try to use the docker IPAddress - 172.23.0.2 (docker inspect the image's ID to get the IP address of the image)

```
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "172.23.0.2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'


services:
  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:12.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user1
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password1
      - POSTGRES_DB=database_db
    volumes:
      - data_db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/12
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    
volumes: 
  data_db_volume:
```

At first, when I tried to connect, it was telling me: role user1 doesn't exist.

So to stop this I ran: `brew services stop postgresql`  on my machine

I think a psql was running locally on the same port because with `lsof -n -i:5432 | grep LISTEN` i keep having information (it stop since I ran stop Postgresql)

Comment: Have you tried with localhost or 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisBougioukos, yes both lead to the same result: connection refused :(

Comment: Then the database works well but it just refuses the connection (probably because of a firewall). Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161674/7237884

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisBougioukos , I checked and my configuration was already like the answer you send me, i also checked pg_hba.conf and it seems correct to accept external connection ... I lost ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so after few days of research and trying on another computer, it seems it was coming from 2 points: the new docker software with a graphic interface that I didn't use before, once this running correctly and a prune done from this place everything started to work fine so I think something was causing error due to an outdated piece of software.

Thank's everyone