# Impossible to connect my symfony 5 app with mysql: postgresql is forced

Tags: mysql, postgresql, symfony5

I'm using mamp the latest php7.4.12 and Apache, i don't understand what is it, i search for this error : "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

In my .env

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@db_docker_symfony:3306/test_docker?serverVersion=5.7"
```

and doctrine.yaml

```
dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused" Error when connecting to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439167/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-error-when-connecting-to)

Comment: No, because i'would like to connect my app with mysql, but i don't know why symfony try to connect with pgsql instead of mysql cf .env file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and basically you might have the postgresql uncommented... this port 5432 is related to the postgresql connection, so you just need to comment this line out using "#" ... as you can see below,

#DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"

leave only you mysql connection uncommented and boom! Happy days hey \o/...

I reackon .env comes with postgresql as a default connection.

Hopefully works for you as well.

Comment: thanks but the line to connect with postgresql is already commented.