# How can I connect to PostgreSQL database remotely from an other network?

Tags: postgresql, tcp, database-connection

I am creating an app that uses a PostgreSQL database server, which I run on a Linux(20.1 Ubuntu) machine. However when the Linux machine is not on the same network as the client that is trying to connect to it, I get the error:

```
Is the server running on host xxx.xxx.xx.xx and accepting TCP/IP connections on port xxxx?
```

I have an exception in my firewall for the port, and since the fact that it all works on the same network implies to me, that my configurations are good, I don't understand what I'm getting wrong. I already tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439167/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-error-when-connecting-to).

My `pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128         md5
host    all all 0.0.0.0/0   md5
host    all all ::/0        md5
```

And my `postgresql.conf` looks like this:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

Can someone help me/ guide me how they managed this? I already vetted all the answers, but if I missed something, apologies for the duplication. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You must have made a basic mistake somewhere. Based on your report, that could be:

- you didn't reload PostgreSQL after changing `pg_hba.conf`
- you didn't restart PostgreSQL after changing `listen_addresses`

You can verify that by running

```
SHOW listen_addresses;
TABLE pg_hba_file_rules;
```

and checking if the result is what you expect.

Apart from that, there are the usual possibilities:

- you are connecting to the wrong server or using the wrong port
- you didn't get all the firewalls (there could be one on both client and server, as well as in between)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add 5432 to Firewall allowed ports.

```
root@vmi543210:~# ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 888/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 20/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 39000:40000/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 7] 8888/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 8] 8443/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 9] 8443/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[10] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[11] 40678/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[12] 888/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[13] 20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[14] 21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[15] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[16] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[17] 39000:40000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[18] 8888/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[19] 8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[20] 8443/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[21] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[22] 40678/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

As you can see, port 5432 is missing.
Add it with following command:

```
root@vmi543210:~# ufw allow 5432/tcp
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
```

Now it's allowed from both ipv4 and ipv6:

```
...
[11] 40678/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[12] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[13] 888/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[14] 20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[15] 21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[16] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[17] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[18] 39000:40000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[19] 8888/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[20] 8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[21] 8443/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[22] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[23] 40678/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[24] 5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

PS: Allowing connection to Postgresql port from outside, will expose it to bruteforce attack.
Use [Fail2Ban](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/howto-secure-a-standard-postgres-port-with-fail2ban.355984/) to create a police to ban this kind of abusive attacks.

Answer (score 0):

After some idle time I have finally found the problem, and it had nothing to do with psql. My network has a double router set-up, and I was only opening ports to the inner router instead of both of them. Thanks for those who tried to help anyway!

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate your solutions, please.