# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony5

I'm a beginner in Symfony and I have e few problems when I run my command

```
symfony server:start
```

I searched before asking you, but I couldn't resolve my problems. These are my errors on the terminal. (I am on Mac)

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException:
   "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request."
at ./Documents/mySymfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 88

Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /""
 at ./Documents/mySymfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136
```

For your information, I also did

```
symfony server:ca:install
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused" Error when connecting to remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439167/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-error-when-connecting-to)

Comment: I already saw it but i don't find this path.

Comment: I suggest separating your issue. 1st, check postgresql database server is up, 2nd check symfony framework works properly  when disable database configuration. If there is no issue in 1,2, then problem might exists in symfony postgres library. Please add 1st,2nd step result in your question.

Comment: problem solved. I had to comment my postgresql line and choose the mysql one