# Azure VPS not opening any ports no matter what

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I'm trying to open several ports on Azure. I have a single VPS with a single network security group with a single virtual network and subnet. Everything seems to be configured correctly, check images:

[image]

[image]

But trying to ping any port, for instance 8080:

```
nc -zv 52.166.131.228 8080
nc: connect to 52.166.131.228 port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

running desperate here, I've followed the guidelines to no avail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal ...any idea what I'm missing??

Comment: Could  you try to use nestat -ant to check whether you port is listening. If possible, give me the result. Please ensure you could telnet 127.0.0.1 8080

Comment: Hi, please ensure your port listening on tcp not tcp6.

Comment: Hi @Walter-MSFT have a postgreSQL server at tpc listeningn at 5432, here is the output of a netstat 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      962/postgres

Comment: Hi, I don't find 8080 is listeng. Please ensure 8080 is listening If you want to access it.

Comment: You could access to port 962 but not access to port 5432 because the port is listening only on 127.0.0.1. Only 127.0.0.1 could access to port 5432.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error, I think you should check your service firstly. I don’t find 8080 is listening according to your output.

Please ensure port 8080 is listening, you could try to use telnet for test in your VM firstly.

> telnet 127.0.0.1 8080

**Notes: NSG could associate to VM and subnet.**

Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-associations) about how to manage NSG

I notice that your port 5432 is only listening on 127.0.0.1. I think you should check your configuration. If you want to access port 5432 with public IP, the port should listening on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Here is a good answer about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150738/cannot-connect-to-postgres-from-remote-host

Comment: you're totally right, I'll check this out, thanks @Walter